# Another Simple convergence theorem proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Question: Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be convergent sequences with $a_n \Rightarrow L$ and $b_n \Rightarrow M$ as $n \Rightarrow \infty$.

Prove that $a_nb_n \Rightarrow LM$

Solution: (My attempt)

WTS:

Let R = sup(|$a_n$|)

(1) $\exists L \in R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$ such that for all $n \in N$, if $n > N_1$, then

$|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{(R + |M|)}$

(2) $\exists M \in R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 > 0$, such that for all $n \in N$, if $n > N_2$, then

$|b_n - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{(R + |M|)}$

Choose $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$

Suppose $n > N$

$$|a_nb_n - LM| = |a_nb_n - a_nM + a_nM - LM| $$

$$= |a_n(b_n - M) + M(a_n - L)| \text{ by algebra}$$

$$\leq |a_n(b_n-M)| + |M(a_n - L)| \text{ triangle inequality}$$

$$< (R + |M|)\frac{\epsilon}{(R + |M|)}$$

$$= \epsilon$$

I have asked this before but I'm wondering if this way to write it is correct as well because this is the style my teacher does it.

Comment: Up to the triangle inequality you are doing fine.
 
But how do you decide that $(|a_n| + |M|) \epsilon < \epsilon$?

How could that possibly be true?

Either work on your triangle inequality and get a subtraction rather than an addition, or replace your $\epsilon$ with something else, say  for example $\epsilon / 2M$

Comment: How is my triangle inequality wrong?

Comment: Ops, sorry, you are right... the inequality is strict... I forget the $\epsilon$ :p Sorry.

Comment: I'm confused. Was it right before or now o-o. (Quantifiers get me super confuse for some reason)

Comment: Before, not now. Use $<$. I get confused with my own inequality in my answer, what is different that what you write in yours, sorry again.

Comment: Sorry I confused $N$ with $\mathbb N$. It looks good.  I would be more concise by defining $A:=\sup |a_n|$ instead of $R$, and use $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$ for the reals and naturals if you're writing this using LaTeX, but that's more of a format issue than one of proof.

Comment: No idea how to get that. "/R" ?

Comment: \mathbb R is $\mathbb R$. Likewise \mathbb N, \mathbb Z, and \mathbb Q are $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb Q$ respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last inequality

$$(|a_n|+|M|)\epsilon<\epsilon$$

is not correct. But if you start your proof with $$|a_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{R+|M|},\quad |b_n-M|<\frac{\epsilon}{R+|M|}$$

where $R:=\sup |a_n|$, then in your step previous to the end you will had

$$(|a_n|+|M|)\frac{\epsilon}{R+|M|}\le(R+|M|)\frac{\epsilon}{R+|M|}=\epsilon$$

---

Note that you can define $R$ for any convergent sequence because if $(a_n)$ is bounded then $(|a_n|)$ is also bounded, and then $R$ exists.

Comment: Hmm. Could I do it instead of them being just less than $\epsilon$, could I let them be less then $\frac{\epsilon}{|a_n| + |M|}$. ?

Comment: No you couldn't, because this bound depends on $n$, which is bad.

Comment: Okay do I just put at the top any variable =  sup |$a_n$|. Then use that variable instead of $a_n$ to finish off the proof? I made an edit, would that be correct?

Comment: @user349557 yes. When you start to learn about some proofs related to the triangle inequality and some $\epsilon$ is hard to grasp at first how to do the things. You only needs practice. This is the reason why I write an answer instead of a hint.

Comment: we use here $R$ because $R$ is a positive constant, same that $|M|$.

Comment: Is the proof correct now? (Its been edited)

Answer (score 2):

If you want $(|a_n|+|M|)\epsilon$ to be less than $\epsilon$, you have to choose a different $\epsilon$ for your applications of definitions. Try first to state that $(|a_n|)_n$ is bounded (a convergent sequence is bounded) by some constant $K$, and choose $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{K+|M|}$.

Apply both convergence definitions to this $\epsilon'$, and you should reach
$$\left|a_nb_n-LM\right|\le (K+|M|)\epsilon'\le \epsilon$$
for every $n\ge N$, and there you are...